# How to differentiate filename without hardcoding it?

Tags: php, foreach

i have a config like so :

```
$CONF['log']['TSEL_MV_GW_SERV101_MT_CONNECTOR_STATUS'] = array(
    'folder'    => $CONF['mainFolder']."/log_sample/tsel",
    'files'     => array(
        'connector_access_log*.log',
        'engine_dr_to_app_hit_dr_url*.log'
    )
);
```

then i'm getting all the files with that pattern that has today date.

```
foreach($CONF['log'] as $label => $arrayData){
    $filePaths = array();
    $today = date("Ymd", time());
    foreach($arrayData['files'] as $filePrefix){    
            $glob       = glob($arrayData['folder']."/".$filePrefix, GLOB_ERR);
            if(count($glob) >= 1){  
                foreach($glob as $file){
                    if(strpos($file, $today)){
                        $filePaths[] = $file;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
     }
```

$filePaths array content :

```
Array
(
  [0] =>/dirpath/connector_access_log_20171025.log
  [1] =>/dirpath/engine_dr_to_app_hit_dr_url_20171025.log
)
```

Now, i need to process each file differently, how can i do this using foreach loop ?

using hardcode such as if(preg_match("connector_access_log")) is not allowed.

this is my approach before :

```
foreach($filePaths as $filePath){
  if(preg_match("/connector_access_log_/", $filePath, $match)){
     #some code
  } else if (preg_match("/engine_dr_to_app_hit_dr_url_/", $filePath, $match)){
   #some code  
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to process diferently, mostly there is an solution which works for every case. Just from your informations, I would write an function with array content as parameter. Anyway in the function you still would need to differ so we need an example what you would do if it hit connector or engine.

Comment: @Doomenik i need to process each of $filePaths content differently, so somehow i need to differentiate which file has which name without using hardcode.

Comment: @Doomenik actually, the process for each file is done, i just need a way to differ the filenames

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is, you could tweak the configuration to store files in [assosiative array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) Eg.

```
$CONNECTOR_ACCESS_LOG = 'connector_access_log'
$ENGINE_URL_LOG = 'engine_dr_to_app_hit_dr_url'
$CONF['log']['TSEL_MV_GW_SERV101_MT_CONNECTOR_STATUS'] = array(
    'folder'    => $CONF['mainFolder']."/log_sample/tsel",
    'files'     => array(
        $CONNECTOR_ACCESS_LOG => 'connector_access_log*.log',
        $ENGINE_URL_LOG => 'engine_dr_to_app_hit_dr_url*.log'
    )
);
```

And then in the loop you can get these keys and switch case between them. Eg.

```
foreach($CONF['log'] as $label => $arrayData){
    $today = date("Ymd", time());
    foreach($arrayData['files'] as $filetype => $filePrefix){    
            $glob       = glob($arrayData['folder']."/".$filePrefix, GLOB_ERR);
            if(count($glob) >= 1){  
                foreach($glob as $file){
                    if(strpos($file, $today)){
                        switch($filetype) {
                         case $CONNECTOR_ACCESS_LOG: doConnection($file); break;
                         case $ENGINE_URL_LOG : doEngine($file); break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
     }
```

Please pardon my php syntax, i am just trying to give an idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't want to use a hardcode you should pass a handler for each file type through your config. Like mostly frameworks do. Please see [yii2 logger](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-logging.html) for more examples. Here is a piece of pseudocode:

```
$CONF['log']['TSEL_MV_GW_SERV101_MT_CONNECTOR_STATUS'] = array(
    new FirstLogger($CONF['mainFolder']."/log_sample/tsel", 'connector_access_log*.log'),
    new SecondLogger($CONF['mainFolder']."/log_sample/tsel", 'engine_dr_to_app_hit_dr_url*.log'),
);
```

Next, proccess your log files by your handler in your handler class.

```
class FirstLogger
{
    protected $dir = null;
    protected $fileWildCard = null;

    public function __construct($dir, $fileWildcard)
    {
        $this->dir = $dir;
        $this->fileWildCard = $fileWildcard;
    }

    public function getFiles()
    {
        $filePaths = [];
        $today = date("Ymd", time());
        $glob = glob($this->dir."/".$this->fileWildCard, GLOB_ERR);
        if(count($glob) >= 1){  
            foreach($glob as $file){
                if(strpos($file, $today)){
                    $filePaths[] = $file;
                }
            }
        }
        return $filePaths;
    }

    public function handleLogs()
    {
        $files = $this->getFiles();
        //some of your logic
    }
}
```

Next, you probably want to create an interface for all of your loggers and an abstract class from which your loggers will be inherited.